# Where can I find F# packages?

Tags: mono

I'm currently install F# manually by downloading the binary distribution from Microsoft, downloading the Mono key, running the Mono installer, then fiddling with my path. Is there a PPA with F# packages that can make my life easier?

Answer (score 6):

The F# license appears to be non-free as it only allows non-commercial use, so it wouldn't be legal to distribute this in a PPA. At best, there could be an fsharp-installer package created, which would automate those steps of downloading & installing it.

Comment: Adobe Flash is in a PPA and it's proprietary -- why not F#?

Comment: I can't find Flash in a PPA, only installer packages. If redistribution isn't allowed by the license, then it can't be put on launchpad.

Comment: Microsoft just anounced they are open sourcing f# http://bit.ly/bMds8c

Answer (score 5):

Ubuntu (.deb) packages for fsharp can be found at http://fsxplat.codeplex.com/

Answer (score 1):

I believe Microsoft said they might open source F# in the future.

---

Comment: they just did http://bit.ly/bMds8c